# How to pass parameter in DELETE request in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am trying to create a `Delete` request in **[Angular 2](http://www.angular2.com/)**.

What I have done is something like this-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
//import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Profile } from '../../dataModel/Profile.ts';   //Data Model

@Component({
    selector: 'profile-list',
    template: require('./profileList.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./profileList.component.css')]
})

export class ProfileListComponent
{
    private _deleteProfileUrl: string = "/api/Profile/Delete";

    constructor(private http: Http)
    {
    }

    public deleteProfile(profileId)
    {
        this.http.delete(this._deleteProfileUrl, new RequestOptions({
            // Have to make a URLSearchParams with a query string
            search: new URLSearchParams('profileId=' + profileId) // <-----
        }));

        alert("Deleted - " + profileId);
    }
}
```

So, I am creating a Delete request like this-

```
this.http.delete(this._deleteProfileUrl, new RequestOptions({
        // Have to make a URLSearchParams with a query string
        search: new URLSearchParams('profileId=' + profileId) // <-----
    }));
```

but it is not working and not giving any error.

Because if the **`deleteProfile`** function is called, only `alert` is coming, but no AJAX request is done.

Because I am having something like this after the function is called-

[image]

I am assuring that API is working perfectly.

So, can anyone please help me what I am doing wrong?

### Moreover-

My complete code can be found [here (if needed)](https://github.com/abrarjahin/Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App).

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observables are lazy. You have to subscribe on them to make the request execute even if you don't want to handle the response. So you can write as follows:

```
this.http.delete(this._deleteProfileUrl, new RequestOptions({
     search: new URLSearchParams('profileId=' + profileId)
   })).subscribe(res => {
     alert("Deleted - " + profileId);
   });
```